# Getting or calculating next IP Address on T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ip-address

I have a table to get list of IP Address. I want to get/calculate IP Address provided that +2 numeric value of last (or any) subnet for each IP.
How can I do this?

For example;

```
SELECT * FROM tblDevices
```

Image: [IP list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmQYT.png)

Just like this;

10.0.128.14 -> 10.0.128.16

10.0.128.140 -> 10.0.128.142

10.0.128.141 -> 10.0.128.143

10.0.128.142 -> 10.0.128.144

Comment: Can you provide your sample data in textual form? Otherwise it's impossible to derive a sql-fiddle from it. Links will also rot sometime. What is the desired result at all?

Comment: I added textual sample data. There is only IP_Address column.

Comment: Where do you specify the subnet mask, or are you just assuming /24? Do you care if the result is a broadcast address (.255) or nonsensical (.256)? IPV6?

Comment: Getting the next valid address is a bit much for SQL.  Just add 2 to the last then you have an answer from diiN_.

Comment: Check my answer ,it uses a number table to do the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx):

```
SELECT PARSENAME(IP_Address, 4) + '.' +
    PARSENAME(IP_Address, 3) + '.' +
    PARSENAME(IP_Address, 2) + '.' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), PARSENAME(IP_Address, 1) + 2)
FROM tblDevices
```

When you want to handle the "255-problem", you could use my just written solution with a `CURSOR`:

```
DECLARE @IP_Address VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT IP_Address
FROM tblDevices
OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @IP_Address
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF(CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 1) AS INT) IN (254, 255))
    BEGIN
        IF(CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 2) AS INT) = 255)
        BEGIN
            IF(CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 3) AS INT) = 255)
            BEGIN
                IF(CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) AS INT) = 255)
                BEGIN
                    SELECT '255.255.255.255'
                END
                ELSE
                    SELECT
                        CASE WHEN CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 1) AS INT) = 254 THEN (CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) AS INT) + 1) + '.0.0.1'
                        ELSE (CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) AS INT) + 1) + '.0.0.2' END
            END
            ELSE
                SELECT
                    CASE WHEN CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 1)AS INT) = 254 THEN PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 3)) + 1) + '.0.1'
                    ELSE PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 3)) + 1) + '.0.2' END
        END
        ELSE
            SELECT
                CASE WHEN CAST(PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 1) AS INT) = 254 THEN PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) + '.' + PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 3) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 2) + 1)) + '.1'
                ELSE PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) + '.' + PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 3) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 2)) + 1) + '.2' END
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 4) + '.' + PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 3) + '.' + PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 2) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (PARSENAME(@IP_Address, 1) + 2))

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @IP_Address
END
```

It's a bit ugly but it works.

Comment: Thank you @diiN_ it works but if last octet is 255, the result is wrong. As HABO said, I care (.255) situation.

If ip address is 192.168.1.255, the next ip address 192.168.2.1

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper I up voted this answer a while ago.  It is not a simple as the .255 situation.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Frisbee I tried edited diiN_'s answer and it worked for me.

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper And you know you are hitting a subnet?

Comment: @Frisbee Yes I know. Maybe there will be no "the .255 situation" anytime on my IP table. I just wonder how to manipulate/calulate next ip address depending on some conditions.

Comment: In your first comment you explicitly said you do care about .255

Comment: @Frisbee I still care about "the .255 problem", I just said "**maybe** there will be this situation".

Answer (score 0):

This works using a number based table...

```
declare @string varchar(20)
set @string='.10.0.128.14.'

;with cte
as
(
select 
substring(@string,n+1,charindex('.',@string,n+1)-n-1) as b,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as rn
from numbers
where 
substring(@string,n,1)='.'
and n<len(@string)
)
select 
distinct stuff((select '.'+case when rn =(select max(rn) from cte) then convert(varchar(10),b+2) else convert(varchar(10),b) end
from cte for xml path('')),1,1,'') b
 from cte
```

> output:10.0.128.16

**Updated as per comments:**

```
declare @string varchar(20)
set @string='.192.168.1.255.'

;with cte
as
(

select 
substring(@string,n+1,charindex('.',@string,n+1)-n-1) as b,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as rn
from numbers
where 
substring(@string,n,1)='.'
and n<len(@string)
)
select
 stuff((select '.'+
case 
when rn =(select max(rn) from cte)  and b=255
then convert(varchar(10),1) 

----
when rn=(select max(rn)-1 from cte)  and ((select b from cte where rn=(select max(rn) from cte))=255)
then convert(varchar(10),b+1)

when rn =(select max(rn) from cte)  
then convert(varchar(10),b+2) else convert(varchar(10),b) 
end
from cte for xml path('')),1,1,'') b,rn,b
 from cte
 where rn=1
```

> output:192.168.2.1

Comment: Did you consider the "255-problem"?

Comment: Thank all of you for help. These answers are useful for me.